# openssl x509 -sigopt algorithms and options list?

Tags: openssl, x.509

Per the [OpenSSL 3.1 documentation for the `x509` subcommand](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man1/openssl-x509.html), the `-sigopt` flag allows one to pass signing options.  The documentation for that flag currently states:

> **-sigopt** *nm:v*
>
> Pass options to the signature algorithm during sign operations. This option may be given multiple times. Names and values provided using this option are algorithm-specific.

But that's it - no references to anything else, unlike, say the [genpkey subcommand documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man1/openssl-genpkey.html)'s `KEY GENERATION OPTIONS` section which (very nicely) documents various algorithms and their options.

As such, how do I:

1. Discover what `x509` signature algorithms are available to me?
2. Discover what options are available for each signature algorithm?

Comment: The signature algorithm is mostly determined by the supplied privatekey (`-key/-signkey` or `-CAkey`) plus the specified or defaulted digest; additional options are the same as [for pkeyutl -sign](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man1/openssl-pkeyutl.html#NOTES) (for RSA you can choose v1.5 or PSS, and for PSS the MGF1 parameters).